# Why does python print ascii rather than unicode despire that I declare coding=UTF-8?

Tags: python, utf-8

```
# coding=UTF-8
with open('/home/marius/dev/python/navn/list.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print lines
```

The file `/home/marius/dev/python/navn/list.txt` contains a list of strings with some special characters, such as æ,ø,å,Æ,Ø,Å. In the terminal, these are all rendered as hexadecimals. I want these to be rendered as UTF-8. How is this done?

Comment: The `# coding:UTF-8` is the encoding **of the source file**. It tells python which encoding should use when parsing string literals(and unicode identifiers, if you are so evil to use them). It doesn't have *anything* to do with encodings of file or the terminal where you print. By the way: there is no such thing as "rendered as UTF-8". What you want is to print the text using the *same encoding of the terminal*(or other output device), so that the terminal can render it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

By decoding the data from UTF-8 to Unicode values, then having Python encode those values back to your terminal encoding automatically:

```
with open('/home/marius/dev/python/navn/list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.decode('utf8')
```

You can use `io.open()` and have the data decoded for you as you read:

```
import io

with io.open('/home/marius/dev/python/navn/list.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Comment: You're not using the io module here

Comment: Using these steps, the terminals adds a u"before-each-string". How can I encode the text so that they are printed as utf-8 characters in the terminal?